# Developing a React Application consuming Remote Server API's

Tags: node.js, reactjs

We have a development machine with IIS Server and all the web services hosted. (e.x https://test.com)

How do we consume these web services while developing the React Application, since the development would generally be done in local machine running Node as localhost with Server of different origin.

Production version will run in the IIS Server because of same origin.

Any help would be great!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just because this one is easy, I will tell you, but you need to check the acceptance criteria on how to post a question.

If you use CRA all you need to do is in yow package.json add a property call ´proxy´ and set the url of the api

```json
{
"name": "proyect-name",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "proxy": "https://domain-where-yow-server-is.com"
}
```

then on your request set only the pathname for example the login endpoint is `https://test.com/api/login`

at yow fetch set `/api/login`

```js
/**
* @param    {Object} credentials
* @property {String} credentials.email
* @property {String} credentials.password
* @returns token
**/
export function login (credentials) {
   return fetch("/api/login", {
       method: "POST",
       body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
       headers:{
          "Content-Type": "Application/json"
       }
   })
}
```